# The color of my label is not changing even though I changed it in my code

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I was trying to change the color of my label. The code does not show any error, but it does not seem to work either.

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)

    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender:Tobject);

  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

  {TAmpel}
  TAmpel = class
  private
    FAmpel1: string;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure schalten();
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

constructor TAmpel.Create;
begin
  FAmpel1 := 'TAmpel1';
end;

procedure TAmpel.schalten();
begin
end;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Label1.Font.Color := clRed;
end;


end.
```

I tried

```
Label1.StyleElements := Label1.StyleElements;
```

but that did not work for me.

It would be nice if somebody could help me... I'm new to lazarus and my teacher does not explain anything

Comment: What do you expecting doing `Label1.StyleElements := Label1.StyleElements`? You're re-assigning the value that's already in there. If you're new to programming then consider reading a book/tutorial. And stop tagging questions with `Delphi` when they have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Changed it. And the StyleElement Thing i found on Stackoverflow. It worked for the guy

Comment: Welcome to the internet - it works through links. Please link to the answer or comment where you found that - I'm very sure you misinterpreted/misread what you've found.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you've written doesn't seem to make much sense. Have you considered finding a good book or online tutorial to learn the basics?

Comment: The original code `Label1.Font.Color := clRed;` in the form constructor works perfectly ok. What made you think it doesn't work? Did you see the text of the label in some other color than red? Or did you not see any text? If the latter case, perhaps you cleared `Label1.Caption` and forgot to assign a new text? We can't tell as you don't explain any details of the problem.